# Selenium with Python- Message: 'operadriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: django, python-3.x, selenium, opera, operadriver

Checking whether a website loads in opera using selenium with python, using the code below:

```
def test_opera_compatability(self):
    driver = webdriver.Opera("functional_tests/operadriver")
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    driver.quit()
```

It returns the following error:

> Message: 'operadriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Similar code for chrome works as intended, which looks like this:

```
def test_chrome_compatability(self):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('functional_tests/chromedriver')
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Key* **`executable_path`** to pass the *absolute path* of the **operadriver** binary as follows:

```
def test_opera_compatability(self):
    driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path='/path/to/functional_tests/operadriver')
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: @AvinMathew The question _heading_ and _description_ mentions of **operadriver** and **opera** respectively, where as your code trials were for **geckodriver**. However I canged the code a bit. Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, I made a typo when typing the code, I updated the code in question thanks for the info

Comment: yes i tried it solved it but gives me a new error "your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible"

Comment: @AvinMathew Great, so your initial error of _Message: 'operadriver' executable needs to be in PATH._ is resolved now. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement please? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: I have less than 15 reputations, I will do it once I have enough reputations.