# How can I run Opera GX browser with Selenium in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, opera

I'm using Selenium and Opera GX is the latest version. When I try to open Opera GX browser with Selenium, I get an exception.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
> Current browser version is 113.0.5672.127 with binary path C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Opera GX\opera.exe (SessionNotCreated)'

The code I tried:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("remote-debugging-port=9222");
options.BinaryLocation = "C:\\Users\\Pc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera GX\\opera.exe";

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 'session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current browser version is 113.0.5672.127 with binary path C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Opera GX\opera.exe (SessionNotCreated)
```

...implies that the [opera](/questions/tagged/opera) browser version you are using internally uses Chrome browsing engine of ***v113.x***. Hence having compatibility issues.

---

### Solution

Ugrade your Opera browser version to the latest version which uses the Chrome browsing engine of ***v114.x***

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Opera binary with OperaDriver Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52794892/7429447)
- [Unable to launch Opera using Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59815127/7429447)

Comment: My Opera GX version is already the most up to date version.

Comment: @Psiko Then you need to downgrade the [OperaDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59085196/7429447) version.